# Does an Indian citizen need a visa to visit Trinidad?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, study, trinidad-and-tobago

Does an Indian citizen, living in Canada on a student permit, need a visa to visit Trinidad for a holiday?

Answer (score 1):

NO, you don't need a visa. Source: https://klm.traveldoc.aero

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to also examine the visa requirements, if any, of any intermediate countries you'll land in while on your way to and from Trinidad. You may need a transit visa for particular intermediate countries or airports.

Answer (score 0):

According to Timatic, the system airlines use to determine whether you can be admitted to a country or not, you do not need a visa for Trinidad itself when traveling on an Indian passport.

> Trinidad and Tobago (TT)
>
> Visa required.
>
> Visa Exemptions: …
>
> Nationals of Brazil, Colombia, Costa Rica, Dominican Rep.,
>     Ecuador, El Salvador, Guatemala, Honduras, **India**, Israel,
>     Japan, Korea (Rep.), Nicaragua, Peru, Russian Fed., Turkey,
>     USA, Uruguay and Venezuela for a maximum stay of 90 days. …
>
> Warning:
>   - Visitors must hold return/onward ticket

Comment: Not sure what the point of the downvote was here.